Use application.yml variable in logback configuration element
im trying to set the debug property of  root element of my logback config.
<configuration debug="logging.debug">

But the problem is logback is loading its config first before the env variable is setup.
Is there a way to configure the debug attribute to be dynamic based on the value in application.yml?
Thanks.

is logging.debug an environment variable?. if so, have you tried <configuration debug="${logging.debug}">.
